# Laravel change Content of Mailable before send

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-9

I currently use Mailable to send mails to users. Data is taken from the database and inserted into the text. I would like to show the text to the user beforehand so that they can make changes if necessary. If the user has made changes, this text should be sent instead of the one generated by Mailable. How can I achieve this?

Current Laravel version: Laravel Framework 9.48.0

Currently, I generate the content using the Blade Template, show this to the user and he can then make changes if necessary. Then I pass the HTML content to the Mailable Layout and send it with that.
I would like to create a separate Mailable for each email template.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What exactly do you have problem with? Could you share your code?

Comment: @StewieSWS I cant share a code because it isnt a code related problem. I just cant figure out how to achive this.

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, you have text with placeholders, you insert some vars into these placeholders then pass it to user, user changes the text and you send it via mail. What exactly do you have trouble with ?

Comment: Basically yes, but im using Mailables for this. I can create a preview or send it directly but not setting the Text outside the Mailable.

Comment: Well then you leave blade template empty, and pass text data that user submitted to send to the view, and then display it like this : `{!! $userText !!}`

Comment: Alright, thats my current approach. I wasnt sure if this is the correct use of mailables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd save the content of the email which your users changed into a blade template file, so when the text changes you can pass the blade template file to the Mailable view method.

Hope this helps.